# How to set up drawable resource folders for Xamarin Android app in Rider IDE

Tags: android, xamarin.android, rider

I'm brand new both to Xamarin and the Rider IDE, but not to Android.  I'm going through some test projects, but when I make a new project, the `ProjectName/Resources` folder is missing things that I would expect to be there, most notably `drawable`.  How can I create or get access to those directories so that I can do something like set the app icon?

I've tried creating a drawable directory, including it, and making sure that the build action is set to AndroidResource, but when I add `Icon = @drawable/icon.png` in the MainActivity, it doesn't recognize the drawable tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for this.  As I mentioned, I created the drawable folder manually, added the icon to it and made sure to right click and `Include` it.  Then, in the manifest, I added `android:icon="@drawable/icon` and that got the icon to show up properly.  So it didn't fix the issue of the folders not being generated, but at least for a simple task like updating the icon, it worked.

Comment: I'm not able to do that for two days after it's posted.  I will when that time has passed.

Answer (score 0):

You can also declare in xaml.cs file, in your xaml form constructor the following:

```
x:Name_of_your_image/icon.ImageSource = (FileImageSource) ImageSource.FromFile("image/icon_name");
```

This way you won't need the drawable folders, as it will automatically provide the source of the image.